# How to fetch instagram last 10 posts and likes using the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am writing social integration class for Facebook & Instagram. Facebook is done using PHP SDK and Graph API now struggling with Instagram. I followed the following procedure:

1. Retrieved Facebook account access token using the Graph API.
2. Retrieved all the user accounts/pages using the access token.
3. Upon selection of the Facebook page checking if the Instagram account is linked to that page using the access token.
4. Using the Instagram account id I am able to fetch the following:

```
'/accountID?fields=follow_count,followed_by_count,media_count,id'
```

5. When trying to fetch this:

```
'/accountID/media?fields=insights.metric(engagement,impressions)&limit=10'
```

I am getting this as a response:

> **(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (media) on node type (InstagramUser)**

Tried Instagram Basic Display API also but using that I can't fetch `followers_count` or `followed_by_count` tried with multiple permissions and also tried to search in Facebook Docs but as of yet don't have any clue.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

To get the fields like `followers_count`, `follows_count`, `media_count` your 4th step should be:-

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/{ig-user-id}?fields=followers_count,follows_count,media_count,id
```

and it will create a response something like this:-

```json
{
  "followers_count": 0,
  "follows_count": 0,
  "media_count": 1,
  "id": "1784144XXXXX"
}
```

To get IG Media insights, your 5th step should be:-

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/{ig-media-id}/insights?metric=impressions,engagement&limit=10
```

and it will return the response like the below:-

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "impressions",
      "period": "lifetime",
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 0
        }
      ],
      "title": "Impressions",
      "description": "Total number of times the media object has been seen",
      "id": "17993550XXXXXX/insights/impressions/lifetime"
    },
    {
      "name": "engagement",
      "period": "lifetime",
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 0
        }
      ],
      "title": "Engagement",
      "description": "Total number of likes and comments on the media object",
      "id": "17993550XXXXXX/insights/engagement/lifetime"
    }
  ]
}
```

To get the `ig-media-id`, you need to call to the following endpoint and it will return the IDs of all the IG Media objects on the IG User::-

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/{ig-user-id}/media
```

and the response would look something like this:-

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "17993550XXXXXX"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "QVFIUkdGRXA2eHNNTUsZAXNGFxQTAtd3U4QjBLd1B2NXRMM1NkcnhqRFdBcEUzSDVJZATFoLWtXMWZAGU2VrRTk2RHVtTVlDckI2NjN0JrUk4yMW13",
      "after": "QVFIUmlwbnFsM3N2cV9FdCa0hDeV9qMVliT0VuMmJyNENxZA180c0t6VjFQVEJaTE9XV085aU92OUFLNFB6Szd2amo5aV9rTlVBcnmEtxcE1HSFR3"
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this will help.

Source:

- [IG Media Insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media/insights#metrics)
- [IG User](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user)

Comment: I tried 4 as you said and getting this:

`{
 "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (followers_count) on node type (InstagramUser)",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "A2uzmxE2g79znNYPzzOFWYS"
  }
}`

Comment: Main point where I stuck is point 5 I tried `accountid/media` call and getting this error using graph explorer tool:

`{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (media) on node type (InstagramUser)",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "AbqsMeviHeLx31At3-TaGSG"
  }
}`

Additionally, in graph explore when I add slash after id it gives these two options only: 

`agencies,authorized_adaccounts`

Comment: @SyedShahzaib, are you sure about using the right {ig-user-id}? Its working fine for me. To get the ig-user-id, you can follow the steps mentioned [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started). A valid ig user will definitely have these field, you can see in the doc itself.

Comment: @SyedShahzaib, to get the ig media insight you need to use ig-media-id as those fields are associated with it.

Comment: @arpit-ain I am using same this is how my code looks like `$fb->get('/me/accounts?fields=instagram_business_account,username');`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem and noticed that `fb_page_id/instagram_business_account` end-point wasn't returning any instagram user id because the page was connected with instagram using page setting whereas it was require to be connected via `Business Meta`